# Ignore null or empty cells when using OleDbConnection?

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledb

[image: Sample Pic]

So this is the sheet that I am reading the data from. Say that I tell my connection string to select A25:B50.

Well, A47 through B50 is empty. If I specifically tell my connection string to only use A25:B46, it works fine, however, when I tell it to also select B50, it tells me that there is no cell there.

How can I use the connection string with up to B50 so that IF I have more data in the future, it would read it as well?

Here is my code to select it :

```
MyCommand2 = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$A25:B46] order by Visits desc", MyConnection2)
Dim DS = New System.Data.DataSet
MyCommand.Fill(DS)
For Each r As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(r.Item("Places"), r.Item("Visits"))
            Next
```

Comment: `...WHERE Places IS NOT NULL` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Select everything 25th and subsequent rows of columns A-B.

```
select * from [Sheet1$A25:B] order by Visits desc
```

And except empty(or whitespace-only) rows.

```
select * from [Sheet1$A25:B] where len(trim(Places)) > 0 order by Visits desc
```

If there are no empty rows in the middle of the data, the empty rows will not be selected.
So, if the data is in the form presented, I do not think you need to have a Where clause.

I assume that a whitespace has been entered from row 47 onwards.
Try to check whether spaces etc are entered in the row which looks like empty.

Comment: The error showed up because I deleted a row from the selection statement. It was expecting data from A25:B46 but when I deleted a row, say A28, it says that row 28 does not exist and just stops. I'll give your statement a try and see if it'll work. Thanks a lot

Comment: Still getting the same error. I have multiple "tables" in 1 excel file, so I have to use a certain range when selecting. My table is from range A25:B46, but I gave it some extra rows in case I add more in the future or remove some.

Comment: How about if I want to filter to not include rows that has empty on all its columns? *All the columns' name is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is not even related to this. The problem is apparently because I was selecting the "Total" value (Visits) by telling my code to do something like : `Tables(0).Rows(21)(1)`

Obviously, if I delete a row, that specific cell's location will no longer exist.
However, @m mukai's solution also worked to improve my code.
Thank you everyone.